# Punchout Iframe issue with Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am trying to integrate the punchout system with Magento 2.

Magento does not allow opening iframe due to security reasons. I have added **'x-frame-options' => '*'** option to the env.php file but still not allow to open the Iframe.

Also, I have changed the below file but I did not get the exact result.

**vendor\magento\framework\App\Response\HeaderProvider\XFrameOptions.php**

I am getting the below response from punchout. After that I am getting a blank screen.

[image]

In the punchout response x-frame-options showing twice.

Can you guide which settings are required to open the site in the Iframe?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

1 - Remove the x-frame-options from the env.php

2 - Override the \Magento\Framework\App\Response\HeaderProvider\XFrameOptions.php file ( don't forget the di.xml ) and comment the content of the __construct

```
class XFrameOptions extends \Magento\Framework\App\Response\HeaderProvider\XFrameOptions
{
    /** Deployment config key for frontend x-frame-options header value */
    const DEPLOYMENT_CONFIG_X_FRAME_OPT = 'x-frame-options';

    /** Always send SAMEORIGIN in backend x-frame-options header */
    const BACKEND_X_FRAME_OPT = 'SAMEORIGIN';

    /**
     * x-frame-options Header name
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $headerName = Http::HEADER_X_FRAME_OPT;

    /**
     * x-frame-options header value
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $headerValue;

    /**
     * @param string $xFrameOpt
     */
    public function __construct($xFrameOpt = 'SAMEORIGIN')
    {
        //$this->headerValue = $xFrameOpt;
    }
}
```

I think this will work!